# Python Cookbook 3rd Edition: Why does this star notation and line split return such a detailed output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the 3rd edition of Python Cookbook by David Beazley and Brian K. Jones, in chapter 1, section 1.2: Unpacking Elements from Iterables of Arbitrary Length, the authors talk about star notation and packing/unpacking variables. In particular, they give this code as an example:

```
>>> line = 'nobody:*:-2:-2:Unprivileged User:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false'
>>> uname, *fields, homedir, sh = line.split(':')
>>> uname
'nobody'
>>> homedir
'/var/empty'
>>> sh
'/usr/bin/false'
>>
```

I don't understand how *fields manages to encompass that string of text, given how there are many ":" that could act as delimiters. How does *fields know to encompass that particular string?

Comment: @ergonaut -- That's specific to parameter unpacking in function calls.  This is more specific to [PEP-3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because * assignment is greedy and grabs any non-explicitly declared assignments. So, in this example, `uname` gets the first return value from `split` and `homedir` and `sh` get the last two. `*fields` gets everything in between.

You can think of it as

```
line = 'nobody:*:-2:-2:Unprivileged User:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false'
info = line.split(':')
uname = info[1]
*fields = info[1:-2]
homedir = info[-2]
sh = info[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `line.split(':')` is the following list:

`['nobody', '*', '-2', '-2', 'Unprivileged User', '/var/empty', '/usr/bin/false']`

If you were to try the following line:

`uname, fields, homedir, sh = line.split(':')`

you would get a ValueError ("too many values to unpack"), because you are trying to unpack a list of 7 values into four variables. The asterisk in front of the "fields" variable tells Python to put "the rest" in there.

In other words, you are telling the Python interpreter to put the first list item into `uname`, the last two into the `homedir` and `sh` variables, and a list of the remaining items from the middle into the `fields` variable.

After your example, `fields` will contain the following:

`['*', '-2', '-2', 'Unprivileged User']`